# Firestore-PHP Reading Nested Arrays

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Anyone can help me to answer this question.
How to read these Firestore's data using for loop.
notice using PHP for the script.
thanx in advance

```
{
  Id:1
  CenterName:"testCenter",
  Sections[
    0:{
        Section_id:1,
        SectionName: "Testing",
     },
    1:{
        Section_id:2,
        SectionName:"Testing2",
      },
     ]

}
```

Comment: Isn't that json missing a `"` at the end of `CenterName:” testCenter,`?

Comment: yes, I forgot to put it